# How can I remove this stuck auger bit when there’s not much room?

Tags: walls, drill, drill-bit

I used a rectangular drill bit extension with an auger bit to drill a hole downwards through a hole for an electrical fixture.

Sadly the bit is stuck now and I can’t manage to get it either in or out. It looks like this:

[image]

I am aware that routing the torque through the 90 degrees is tough and I carefully started from small to big. I have done this a few times and it never happened. Now I am in desperation. Main problem is I don’t have room to apply lever and I can’t use the wall because I would destroy it.

Is there any way to get this thing out?

Comment: Have you tried reversing direction of the drill?  Deep wood drilling usually best done by drilling a bit and pulling out to clean the hole, then repeating.  A small block of wood with a ply bar/lever helping when you have the drill in reverse might help.

Comment: You can't push it through? Or you don't want to? It looks like you've already got some wall to repair.

Comment: Pipe wrench with cheater pipe if necessary. Crowfoot "socket" to fit bit flats with ratcheting socket wrench. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options from cheap to expensive.

Block of wood and pry bar with drill in reverse if engaging like crip suggests.

Vice Grips like fred.u suggests.

Crow foot socket with short extension bar and ratchet per kreemoweet.

A good right angle attachment like the milwaukee 49-22-8510

A good right angle drill like the milwaukee right angle corded drill - hard to tell how much clearance you have on your wall hole.

Also don't use those auger bits.  Use self feed spade drill bits.  I can see your plaster and lath, you are drilling sill plates that are old growth and have hardened.

Comment: Great comprehensive summary. I was indeed able to turn it our with a ratchet. Lot of sweat and lot of work and I did not have much room but after hundreds of "single click" turns I got it out. I will avoid the Augers in the future but I used them because the bit length is short, so I can insert them via the 90deg extension. My spades are all too long for that.

Comment: you can get stubby self feed space bits - diablo has a kit.

Comment: Not sure I'd recommend a spade bit over an augur bit for drilling old-growth framing. I dulled 4 spade bits trying to drill a single hole in a bottom plate for wiring in my 1890s built house. A screw-feed augur bit goes right through...

Comment: @freeman which brand of spade bit, did it have the self feed screw?  The nice thing with spade bits is you can just sharpen them up with a grinder.

Comment: It was 30 years ago, I have no recollection of the brand. No screw feed on it, though.

Comment: yeah i used the old school spade bits on old growth petrified in 2006 and they just started smoking - took an hour a hole.  self feed is like a knife through butter.  the cutter geometry is also changed with a bit of a hook on the leading edge vs just a flat blade.

Answer (score 5):

If you can disengage the drill motor and ninety degree drive, using a pair of clamping pliers (ViseGrips™) or a suitably sized wrench to fit the end of the drill bit may provide you with sufficient torque/leverage to rotate the bit sufficiently for removal.

Even a third or a sixth rotation repeated should work the drill bit free.